# Google Maps: Can't Change Marker Icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created a method to find user location using Geolocation and i pass that location to my function to make a request to a web service. After data from the web service received, some marker will be added to the map. The marker was shown to the map, but apparently when i try to change the marker icon, the marker was dissapear. i've tried to put it in the same folder and the image name is correct and i've tried to open the image in my browser and it open. Here is my code, can anyone please help me?

```
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;
        initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        get_json(lat,lon,function(data){
            var i, marker;
            var location;
            for (i=0; i<=data.cells.length;i++) {
                location = new google.maps.LatLng(data.cells[i].lat, data.cells);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map,
                    icon: "../img/icon_bts.png"
                });    
            }
        });
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can try with the absolute path of the icon. (Just to check)

Comment: Can you try open up your browser's console to see if there is any javascript error getting thrown? cltr+shift+j for chrome

Comment: I suspect it should be some simple file not found error because markers stopped getting rendered once after the icon code gets kicked in. An exception must have been thrown thus preventing the marker rendering code from taking place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you accidentally deleted part of your script when you added your own marker. Assuming you posted your literal code fragment (and if you didn't, *you really should*), the following line

```
location = new google.maps.LatLng(data.cells[i].lat, data.cells);
```

*could never work*. The [constructor of LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) takes two number arguments: if `data.cells[i].lat` is a number, `data.cells` definitely isn't. I assume that line should read something like

```
location = new google.maps.LatLng(data.cells[i].lat, data.cells[i].lng);
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, just look in the browser console what the actual error is and report it as part of your question.

Comment: Thank you, silly me. Now the marker's icon was change. But If you don't mind i ask another question, why i still keep getting error undifined data.cells[i] even though the markers was shown?

Comment: Because your loop condition is off by one. Use <, not <= .